# How to select multiple rows if their content is not known in advance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working on the search functionality for my pet project. This functionality suggests that user inputs one or few words, and the search algorithm will parse required tables in order to discover if these words (or whole phrase) are present in the requested column. Technically, using SQL I can solve this with the simple `OR` condition, but I would like to solve it with the sqlalchemy capacities. Existing solutions suggest using `func.or_` function, but it works correctly if you know an amount of items in advance. So it is not my case, as I need to fill them dynamically. Thus I finished up with the next solution:

```
def ext_search(q="", in_=None, div_id="", by=None, sort_asc=False, strict=True):
    """
    Searchs for the :q: in the database
    :param q: Search string
    :param in_: a class field from pp.models where a search will be performed
    :param div_id: ID of a division in which search will be performed
    :param by: a property of a class from pp.models that will be used
        for sorting
    :param sort_asc: defines sorting order
    :param strict: if search should be run for a phrase or words
    :return:
    """

    srt = asc if sort_asc is True else desc
    by = by if by else in_
    if strict:
        lq = [q]
    else:
        lq = q.split(' ')
    rv = db_session.query(in_.class_).filter(in_.class_.division_id == div_id)
    for i in range(len(lq)):
        lq[i] = u"{}.{} = '{}'".format(in_.class_.__tablename__, in_.key, lq[i])
    lqs = " OR ".join(lq)
    rv = rv.filter(text(lqs)).order_by(srt(by))
    if sort_asc:
        rv = rv.order_by(asc(by))
    else:
        rv = rv.order_by(desc(by))

    rv = rv.all()
    logger.debug("Found '{}' items for '{}' in '{}'.".format(len(rv), q, in_))
    return rv
```

The thing I don't like here is the way I'm trying to figure-out the table and column name, as well as using `text()`, as it violates my initial requirements. So my question is if any better way to fulfill the issue exists for the moments when you need to use multiple OR clauses but you don't know how many items you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a dynamic language and therefore supports making dynamic function calls and attribute access. So, you can do it like this:

```
or_(*(in_ == word for word in q.split()))
```

Or, alternatively, since it's strict equality, you can use `IN` instead:

```
in_.in_(q.split())
```

Comment: Somehow I thought that `in_` works only for having a complete phrase on the left side versus partial on the right, while I needed vice versa. Also using `or_` in the way you suggested is the thing I didn't know about.